Can a secret variable contain within it the syntax for another variable, without the variable being expanded?
I have a secret variable in a variable group that can contain the format $(...), however I want this to be treated literally, is there a way to do this? Everything I've tried so far expands the inner variable.
trigger: none

variables:
  - group: SomeVariableGroup # containing variable someVar with value hello$(anotherVar)
  - name: anotherVar
    value: XXX

stages:
  - stage: stage1
    jobs:
      - job: job1
        steps:
          - bash: echo $(someVar) # This should print hello$(anotherVar) NOT helloXXX


Ideally variable groups should contain values such as passwords, tokens, etc - not Azure DevOps expressions/logic that will be evaluated when the pipeline runs.

Hi @AS3, Have you got a chance to check the answer by Rui below? It is by-sign that variables referenced using $( ) syntax are recursively expanded. Hope the information helps.

Variables referenced using macro syntax $( ) that are set at the same variable scope are recursively expanded - that's why running echo '$(someVar)' prints 'helloXXX', instead of 'hello$(anotherVar)'.
But on the other hand, non-existing variables (or variables set at different scopes) won't be expanded, i.e. if myvar variable is not found it will be rendered as $(myvar).
If someVar and anotherVar are used for different purposes I suggest you set/reference these variables at the job level, to make it available only to the job where it's really needed.
Example:
trigger: none

stages:
  - stage: stage1
    jobs:
      - job: job1
        displayName: 'Job that uses local variable'
        dependsOn: []
        variables:
          - name: anotherVar
            value: XXX
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - bash: echo '$(someVar)'    #  Output: $(someVar)
          - bash: echo '$(anotherVar)' #  Output: XXX

      - job: job2
        displayName: 'Job that uses variable group'
        dependsOn: []
        variables:
          # Contains variable 'someVar' with value 'hello$(anotherVar)'
          - group: SomeVariableGroup
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - bash: echo '$(someVar)'    #  Output: hello$(anotherVar)
          - bash: echo '$(anotherVar)' #  Output: $(anotherVar)

